# Arction "no valid licence available error"

Tags: lightningchart

I am currently using Arction Lightning Chart on my application. It used to work fine but now it is throwing an error named on the topic for a while and afterwards error is disappearing. Also I have valid licence.
I could not found any solution on the internet and as a last resort I have decided to open a topic.

Comment: Could you include a code snippet showing how you input your license?

Comment: We are not making input our licence because our Arction dlls are all licenced dlls.

Comment: Oh, I believe this is about LightningChart .NET.
The lightningchart Stack Overflow thread is only for JS userbase, please contact support@lightningchart.com for .NET support

Comment: I think we are going to do like that. I have written this post in case someone could answer.